# Doing typeof variable throws an error when used inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, scope

For some reason when I try to access the `rates` variable inside the `for-in` loop, it throws a `ReferenceError`, but I can use it just fine right before the loop. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this behavior. Even doing `typeof` throws this error, but it works fine on a variable that was never used at all:

```js
const test = 1;
const rates = await Rate.find({
    propertyId: property._id,
    ratePlanId: {$in: ratePlanIds},
 });

console.log(test); // 1
console.log(typeof rates); // object

for (const i in ratePlans) {
  console.log(test); // 1
  console.log(typeof asdlkfjasdajsfl); // undefined
  console.log(typeof rates); // ReferenceError: rates is not defined
  //[... rest of code]
}
```

Comment: This means you have defined another `let rates`, `const rates` or `class rates {}` in that `for` loop body, below that part which you did show us. You experience the temporal dead zone.

Comment: @Bergi Ohhh. It's further down. Thanks!